# Unable to Use Google+ API

Tags: php

I was attempting a google sign in using the following code:

```
<code>

function gLogin(){ //handle the login process for retrieving google User's email with 
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE,Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME,Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_LOGIN));
    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
    try{
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $me = $plus->people->get('me');
        //deal with non-domain Emails
        if($me['domain'] !== 'xxx.org' && $me['domain'] !== 'xxx.org'){
            $client->revokeToken();
            $errorUrl = ERROR_URI . '?error=wrongDomain';
            http_response_code(302);
            header('Location: ' . $errorUrl);
            die();
        }
        $displayName = $me['displayName'];

    //get the email
    $oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $emails = $oauth->userinfo->get();
    $email = $emails->getEmail();
    //too nested, going to sqlLogin
    sqlLogin($email, $displayName);
    $client->revokeToken();
}catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());    
}   
}
</code>
```

When I did, I would get the following error:

> {\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "usageLimits",\n
>   "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",\n    "message": "Daily Limit for
>   Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",\n
>   "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"\n   }\n  ],\n 
>   "code": 403,\n  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use
>   Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."\n }\n}\n,

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my own error. Since I was redirecting from index.php and not keeping the access token, I had to manually set it with $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); (I wasn't keeping the token due to some code standardization that I wanted). Updated code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setRedirectUri('replace_me'); //not sure if I need the redirectUri here, but it was one of the things I tested
$client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE,Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME,Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_LOGIN));
try{
    $error = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    print_r($error);
    $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); /*access tokens must be requested with the following line if you are not keeping them, otherwise it will be an unauthenticated request*/
    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
    $me = $plus->people->get('me');
    //deal with non-domain Emails
    if($me['domain'] !== 'xxx.org' && $me['domain'] !== 'xxx.org'){
        $client->revokeToken();
        $errorUrl = ERROR_URI . '?error=notDomain';
        http_response_code(302);
        header('Location: ' . $errorUrl);
        die();
    }
    $displayName = $me['displayName'];      
    //get the email
    $oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $emails = $oauth->userinfo->get();
    $email = $emails->getEmail();
    //too nested, going to sqlLogin
    sqlLogin($email, $displayName);
    $client->revokeToken();
}catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());    }
```